# Rotativa Issue printing RAW HTML

Tags: rotativa

(More specific Giorgio Bozio)

I have been using Rotativa for the last year to print simple html to pdf and its been working fantastic. Very happy with product, but now recently i have been trying to do something a little more advance and i keep having the same issue.

Normally i would send Rotativa a simple invoice view (Predefined HTML) with model data populated via Razor and this worked well, but now i am trying to implement template's for my invoices. Customers can create their own template layouts with a custom 3rd party form designer and then upload its template file into my site. I take this file and parse it and generate the elements of the invoice with stringbuilder and div tags. I then send the generated HTML to the view that uses a @HTML.Raw() to populate the invoice html. Rotativa then takes this View and generates a pdf, but when it generates the pdf its quality of the text is horrible and blurry. Thus it generates the template correctly, but does some sort of shrinking or something to make the text not look crisp.

I have tried everything, from playing with custom switches to playing with the dimensions of the html.

When i copy the generated html to a view and just generate the pdf plainly then it prints fine, but as soon as i push the html to the view with HTML.Raw i seem to land up with fussy text.

Giorgio Bozio, does Rotativa have a issue with Html.Raw? or can you perhaps open a dialog with me to try and resolve this issue? Really hope you can help me...or someone can help me. Desperate and dont really want to change Rotativa for something else.

Please help.

Comment: Are you using ViewAsPdf? It's really odd that you say that taking the actual HTML to a view shows that text ok... something has to be different. Can you   add you code to the question? Perhaps adding  a super simple compete view/html.

Comment: Hi Giorgio, thank you for your reply. I finally solved the issue, took me a couple of days to figure out the problem. The issue was background-color. When i draw the square div containers that hold the different information parts, eg. The customer address container, or the details container that houses the line items of the invoice....if i set a background color like white then the text printed is fussy and blurred, but if i dont define a background-color then the text prints perfectly.

Comment: Strange issue i know....and took me a while to figure out. I compared the generated html of pages that printed perfectly with the html of those that did not, and all i could find differently was the fact that a extra # tag in the color definition broke the style and thus the prints printed properly.

Comment: With this resolved i am encountering another small problem, and that is when i click print and the preview of the invoice comes up, it shows the preview perfectly and the right amount of pages.....but when i print i keeps printing a extra blank page. Is this a common issue? and do you perhaps know the reason? Below is the code i use;

Comment: return new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf("~/Views/_PrintTemplates/CustomPrinting_Template.cshtml", model: ViewHTML.ToString())
                        {                
                            CustomSwitches = "--disable-smart-shrinking",                            
                            PageOrientation = Rotativa.Options.Orientation.Portrait,
                            PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.A4,
                            PageMargins = new Rotativa.Options.Margins(2, 2, 2, 2),
                            PageWidth = 210,
                            PageHeight = 303 // 297};

Comment: As you can see, previously i increased the PageHeight to 303 which strangely ensured the page fits in on one page....could this have a impact on the print and cause it to print a extra blank page?

Comment: Ok....I resolved this too :-) Sorry to waste your time. I decreased PageHeight to 300 to just fit the invoice onto a single page and now it prints only the invoice and no extra blank pages....Hooray!!! :-)

Comment: Ok George, glad to know you solved everything! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved Text printing issue by removing background-color definitions on Div containers.

Resolved extra blank page printing issue by reducing PageHeight on Rotativa Customswitches

:-)